# Avoid symbols except some which I specified

Tags: ios, objective-c

Possible Duplicate: Separate digits in an NSString to display a phone number

Objective:

- I want to allow the user to type only **' - '**, **' + '** symbol and numbers in a text field.
  If the user type other than i specified then remove it programmatically,
  after i will give alert to the user.

How can i do it? Please reply with which members/property/delegates/interface helpful to these objective.
More than to send whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this simply be like this:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField.tag == 3)
    {

        NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."]; //This allows user type in only numbers and - +
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
        {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) //Here, it checks if the entered character is in the characterSet, if it's not, it wouldn't allow the user go ahead.
            {
                return NO; //Restrict the user from entering other characters
            }
        }

        return YES; //Allow the user enter the characters specified above
    }

    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: @GenieWanted- Friend: What happened to you. Remove '!' in 'IF' condition according to my objective.

Comment: @UdanPirappu - நண்பா, removing the ! will cause the user type in alphabets too.. You only want to enter numerics and - + symbols. Correct a?

Comment: @GenieWanted- நண்பா, Your code only allow to type alphabets. Please check that friend(நண்பா).

Comment: நண்பா, did you run the above code and tried entering some values? It works for me as expected. Make sure you've set the delegate for your textField. எனக்கு பாக்காவ வொர்க் ஆகுது..

Comment: நண்பா, Sorry. I put invertedSet in your code. Thats why it happened.

Comment: If i put tag value is 3 for more than one textField, then what happened.

Comment: If you set the same tag value for multiPle textFields, you will end uP reflecting the same results for those textFields with tag 3. However, having the same tag for multiPle controls will not be advisable.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `NSCharacterSet` in to one of the delegate of textFiled `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` using Bellow code:-

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-,+"] invertedSet];

    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];


    NSLog(@"%@",filtered);

  if(filtered.length>0)
  {
      //do your stuff
  }
  else
  {
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not allowed" message:@"You Enter not allowd charactore" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

  }
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

---

`NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789*#"] invertedSet];`user can able to enter only mention characters **0123456789-,+** in to textfiled.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the number set as

```
#define NUMBERS @"0123456789+-"
```

Then in the delegate function of the text field

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
            NSCharacterSet *cs;
            NSString *filtered;
            cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS] invertedSet];
            filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            return [string isEqualToString:filtered];"
}
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: I will try. Whats the usage of 'invertedSet'.

Comment: invertedSet: Returns a character set containing only characters that don’t exist in the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

There is an delegate of UITextField named UITextFieldDelegate

Implement the method:

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

return NO if `string` contains invalid characters and give alert to the user.

How to judge if there is some invalid characters in the `string`, here is an example

```
NSCharacterSet * invalidCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-1234567890"] ;
invalidCharacters = [invalidCharacters invertedSet] ;
NSRange r = [searchString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invalidCharacters] ;
if (r.location == NSNotFound) {
    // there isn't invalid character
} else {
    // there is
}
```

Comment: Ok. You said that to use this delegate and follow with logical operator to find the valid characters. But i heard that, there are many dynamic ways to avoid symbols. Ex: CharacterSet.

Comment: Is there any other idea from you?

Answer (score 0):

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

in string you will find the character according to it, you can display what ever you want.